# Tkinter module - program will just run then stop and won't open the window

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I need help, I am doing a budget calculator and using `tkinter` for the first time and wondered why it is not working...

When I run it, it will just end straight away and when I put the `root = Tk()` at the end it comes up with an error.

I really need help, my code is below...

```
from time import sleep
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter import messagebox, ttk, Tk

root = Tk()

class GUI():

    def taskbar(self):

        menu = Menu()
        file = Menu(menu)
        file.add_command(label="Exit", command=self.exit_GUI)
        file.add_command(label = "Information", command=self.info_popup)        

    def Main_Menu(self):
        topFrame = Frame(root)
        topFrame.pack()
        bottomFrame = Frame(root)
        bottomFrame.pack(side=BOTTOM)

        Income_button = Button(topFrame, text="Enter your incomes", command=self.Income)
        Expense_button = Button(topFrame, text="Enter your expenses", command=self.Expense)
        Total_button = Button(bottomFrame, text="View Results", command=self.Total)
        Income_button.pack()
        Expense_button.pack()
        Total_button.pack()

    def Income(self):
        pass

    def Expense(self):
        pass

    def Total(self):
        pass

    def exit_GUI(self):
        exit()

    def info_popup():
        pass

g = GUI()
g.Main_Menu()
g.taskbar()
g.Income()
g.Expense()
g.Total()
g.exit_GUI()
g.info_popup()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are exiting before you ever get to the `mainloop` with:

```
g.exit_GUI()
```

That method is calling the standard `exit()` and stopping the entire script. Remove or comment out the above call. You will also need to add `self` as an argument to `info_popup` to get your script to run:

```
def info_popup(self):
    pass
```

Comment: While this might work, I wouldn't recommend having a `root` in the global scope being referenced in the `GUI()` though, it just feels like a slippery slope.  But of course, that's not part of this question.